# Function To Match The Last Character Of A String

Tags: c, pointers, char

So this is a problem : Write the function strend(s,t), which returns 1 if the char t occurs at the end of the string s, and zero otherwise.

This is my code:

```
int strend(char*, char);
int main()
{

    int n = -1;
    char str1[6] = "Hello", char1;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    char1 = getchar();
    n = strend(str1, char1);
    printf("n = %d", n);
    return 0;

}

int strend(char* str1, char str2)
{
    while(*str1 != '\0')
    {
        str1++;
    }

    if(*str1 == str2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However the character matching does not perform as intended. Where the mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Note: The problems asks you to check for a string, not a single character.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck You are most correct, did miss that!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It was an unintended typo, thanks!

Comment: to help people help you, please show how your code does not perform as intended, with example input, and output from your code (as well as expected output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing the character to the `\0` string terminator.

```
int strend(char* str1, char str2)
{
    if (*str1 == '\0') {
        return 0;
    }

    while(*str1 != '\0') /* removed ; that shouldn't be there */
    {
        str1++;
    }
    /* at this point, str1 is pointing to the 0-terminator */

    str1--; /* pointer now points to last character of the string, not 0-terminator */

    if(*str1 == str2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get no output :(

Comment: @Debojyoti Did you also remove `;` after while loop?

Comment: @AntonH It works now ! How did I get that in the first place :O Thanks

Comment: @Debojyoti I missed it on first read through. Caught it because Quentin made me edit my question :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll try my own explanation.
Suppose your `while()` loop has reached the last non-zero character of your string `str1`.
In this case, the line `while( *str1 != '\0' )` is "asking" if this character is zero or not.
Since it is the character that you are looking for, logically it cannot be `'\0'`.
Then the comparison expressión is "true", and the increment `str1++;` is performed.
Now `*str1` is the character `'\0'`, and the immediate next iteration gives "false" when evaluating `*str1 != '\0'`.

Then the `while()` block is finished, and the program continues in the line `if(*str1 == str2)`.
Here, the value `*str1`, which is `'\0'`, is compared against `str2`, giving always the result "false".

However, the desired character is still in the immediate previous memory position of `str1`.
So, you can decrement `str1` and then comparing, or well you can compare `str2` against `(str1 - 1)`.

```
   // Option 1
   str1--; 
   if(*str1 == str2)

   //Option 2
   if ((str1 - 1) == str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any error checking, (you can do that) here is a *one liner* that will check that the last character is matched:

```
int strend(char* str1, char str2)
{
    return ((str1[strlen(str1)-1]) == str2)?(1):(0);    
}
```

***Or*** in a more readable form:

```
int strend(char* str1, char str2)
{
    return ((str1[strlen(str1)-1]) == str2);    
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing this as an unreadable one-liner, I would suggest that you write it on multiple lines. Also, the `?:` is superfluous clutter, the result of `==` is already 1 or 0 (essentially it is a boolean). `size_t length = strlen(str1); return str1[length-1] == str2;`

Comment: @Lundin - Edited (with more readable option), however, the intent of the answer was to show a one-liner, and to show other, simpler possibilities.  I happen to like ?: operator :)  But you are correct, I could just return the expression.  Thanks.